# How to make global objects for multithreaded applications

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, boost, thread-safety

I have a boost multi_index container

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    myData, 
        indexed_by<    
            random_access<>,  // keep insertion order
            ordered_non_unique< member<myData, time_t, &myData::timestamp> >
        > 
> myContainerType;


class myDataOperator
{
    myContainerType myContainer;
    // some functions for inserting and searching myContainer 
}
```

And another class which has general functionalities for whole project

```
class MasterClass
{
private:
    myDataOperator myOp;

public:
    // some general functionalities
    // some procedures using myContainer
}
```

And two classes which are going to work in threads by using the class `MasterClass` functionalities

```
class ThreadClass1
{
    private:
    MasterClass master;

    // some function calls of MasterClass with master
    // thread 1 internal functionalities
}

class ThreadClass2
{
    private:
    MasterClass master;

    // some function calls of MasterClass with master
    // thread 2 internal functionalities    
}
```

Whenever I run the project, every thread (there will be more than 6 threads) creates its own `MasterClass` and `myContainer` object. What I want is to have one `MasterClass` object that handles all the functionalities and full control over the container by `myDataOperator` and one `myContainer` onject for all threads. So they need to be some kind of `Singleton` or `Global` I guess, but I don't know how to do it.

As far as I searched internet, I saw that I need some kind of `synchronization` or `locking`. So how can I make `MasterClass` and `myContainer` global (or singleton) where they serve all the threads?

Thanks.

**Note: I am using Visal C++ in Visual Studio 2008 on a Win7 x64 computer**

Comment: You have already answered your question - you need singleton :)

Comment: But I think singleton is not the best practice for this type of problem thats why I said "some kind of Singleton". Some people say it is not thread safe.

Comment: There are several ways to implement singleton. Some of them are thread safe.

Comment: I am not really sure what you intend by this one MasterClass object. Usually a Singleton or another construction that needs synchronization should be avoid if possible. Even if they are thread safe, what benefit do i have if i have to synchronize often?

Maybe another approach may be helpful, task based like tbb? https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

Comment: I mean myContainer must be same for all threads. And the threads must not reach the array directly but via MasterClass object. Since myContainer is a member of MasterClass as well in the project scope I have to have one MasterClass object that handles all the operations related with myContainer. Otherwise all threads will create their own MasterClass object and container as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need thread-safe singleton here.

http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2012/10/21/implementing-a-thread-safe-singleton-with-c11/

Comment: unfortunately it is c++11. I'm working in Visual Studio 2008 enivironment

Comment: You can look at boost::call_once from Boost library.